# Qt 5.7 WebEngineView, HTML5 audio/video and WebRTC

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

Documentation suggests that the latest QtWebEngineView should support WebRTC and HTML5 audio (I also want WebAudio API).
I'm using QtQuick 2 and QT 5.7, and the QML WebEngineView (1.1) and WebView don't support getUserMedia nor HTML5 audio.

Is it possible to have access to WebRTC and Web Audio API using QML?
Or do I have to use C++ and calling the widgets directly?  (everything is supported with the webenginewidgets/demobrowser example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a good solution to this, but recent versions of Qt don't have this issue.  I ended up not going the Qt route.